# C++ math answer different than in class

Tags: c++, math

I wanted to practice math in c++ and I tried making a program that answered this question from math class

> 0 < r < 1, find the number of rational r values for which the
>   numerator and the denominator add to make 1000 where r is in simplest
>   form

After an hour or two debugging, I finally got something that makes it through all the numbers. In class, the answer was 200. I got 216. Run for yourself

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

bool rprime_test(int a, int b) {
    int tmp = 2;
    std::cout << a << "/" << b;
tmp1:
    for (tmp; (tmp < a) && (a % tmp != 0); tmp++) {
    }

    if ((b % tmp == 0 && a % tmp == 0) || b % a == 0) {
        std::cout << " == irreduced\n";
        return false;
    } else if (!tmp < a) {

        std::cout << " == reduced\n";
        return true;
    } else {
        //std::cout << tmp << ","<< a << std::endl;
        goto tmp1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int r = 0, a = 1;
    int b = 1000 - a;
    while (a < b) {
        if (rprime_test(a, b)) {
            r++;
        }

        std::cout << "total = " << r << std::endl;
        a++;
        b = 1000 - a;
        //std::cout << "assigned " << a << "/" << b << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "final result = " << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

please I don't know what I did wrong for this. Also, is there any better way to optimize this?

Comment: You should include code directly on SO, not via pastebin.  Have you gone through your answers to see if you can find one of the 16 presumably wrong ones, then tried to work out why it was generated by your program?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Please, even the first three results collectively make no sense: *1/999 == irreduced
total = 0
2/998 == irreduced
total = 0
3/997 == reduced
total = 1* - First, 2/998 is certainly not irreducible. 3/997 is irreducible. The total there should be 2 regardless of which of these sets of reducibility conclusions you use.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is with your rprime_test function. Without digging too much into your existing function, try using the gcd. Two numbers a and b are an irreducible fraction when they are "coprime," which is when their "greatest common denominator" (gcd) is 1. The way you compute the gcd of two values is with the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

```
int gcd (int a, int b) {
    return b % a == 0 ? a : gcd (b % a, a);
}
```

And your check becomes

```
if (gcd (a, b) == 1) {
    a++;
    /* etc */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works:

```
#include <iostream>

int gcd(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    if (b < a) {
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
    int r = a % b; 
    while (r != 0) {
        a = b; 
        b = r; 
        r = a % b; 
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i != 500; ++i) {
        if (gcd(1000 - i, i) == 1) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/sgHDk4)